# print value from tuple in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know this is super basic but it's giving me problems. I have a tuple that I want to return a specific value from.

Code:

```
mytuple=[('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F','G'),('H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M','N')]
print mytuple[0:1]
```

Desired Output:

```
B
```

Answer (score 2):

The object that you've named `mytuple` is not, in fact, a tuple.  It is a list containing two tuples.  That's probably what's confusing you.

To get the first of the two tuples you would do:

```
 my_real_tuple = my_tuple_list[0]
```

and then to get the second element of the tuple:

```
print my_real_tuple[1]
```

These can be simplified into

```
print my_tuple_list[0][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you are looking for, you need to specify the index of the list + the index of the tuple.

```
print mytuple[0][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two separate indexes:

```
print mytuple[0][1]
```

`mytuple[0]` will return the first tuple in `mytuple`:

```
>>> mytuple[0]
('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G')
>>>
```

We then index that with `[1]` to return the item at index `1`:

```
>>> mytuple[0][1]
'B'
>>>
```

Your current code is no different than:

```
print mytuple[:1]
```

which slices the list `mytuple` and gets everything before index `1` (which is just the first tuple):

```
>>> mytuple[:1]
[('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G')]
>>>
```